# Form validation of many-to-many relationship input field with Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4, ardent

I have a many-to-many relationship between my articles and tags table, and want to require the user to input tags in the create/edit article form. I am using [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) for my validation and have the following in my article model:

```
class Article extends Ardent {

  use PresentableTrait;
  protected $presenter = 'presenters\ArticlePresenter';

  protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'title', 'description', 'content', 'published'];

  public static $rules = array(
    'title' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'content' => 'required|min:250',
    'category_id' => 'exists:categories,id',
    'tags' => 'required'
  );

  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'article_tag', 'article_id', 'tag_id');
  }

}
```

My form input:

```
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('tags')) has-error @endif">
    {{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags') }}
    @if(!isset($article))
        {{ Form::text('tags', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    @else
        {{ Form::text('tags', $article->present()->implodeTags, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    @endif
    @if ($errors->has('tags')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('tags') }}</p> @endif
</div>
```

But the validation fails even if I enter something in the tags field, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this; the `tags` variable wasn't being passed to [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent).

To fixed this I added the `tags` to the `fillable` variable:

```
protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'title', 'description', 'content', 'published', 'tags'];
```

Further I added the following code, explained in the [Ardent readme file](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#automatically-purge-redundant-form-data):

```
public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;

function __construct($attributes = array()) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->purgeFilters[] = function($key) {
        $purge = array('tags');
        return ! in_array($key, $purge);
    };
}
```

Comment: Would the first part (adding 'tags' to the fillable array) be enough? I'm trying to get this to work in my situation, and am unable to.

Comment: That depends, in my case I do not actually have a `tags` field in the `article` table. I only need to pass it to Ardent. The latter code purges the `tags` variable so it does not try to write it to the table.

Comment: You misunderstood, but it's ok :) I also do not have my external field in the main table, but I'm using laravel administrator, which  unsets any "external" data fields prior to saving, preventing this from working.

Answer (score 0):

It's now [possible](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/commit/a8bc5d2c47d5c403838b62ef6040f385e5263eb9) to validate relationship data in the latest version of Administrator.